# Convergence of a sequence with nonincreasing real terms on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $a_0 \geq a_1 \geq ... \geq a_n \geq ...$ Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ converges for all $|z|=1, z \neq 1$.

My take was this: let $z \in \delta D(0,1)- \{1\}$. Then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n e^{n*i*\theta}$$ for some $\theta \neq 0$. But I don't know how to proceed from here. I had other ideas, including taking a sequence (perhaps along the same line from the origin so that the argument is constant) $z_n \to z, z_n \in D(0,1)$ since at each $z_n$ the sequence of partial sums will converge uniformly to the full series at $z_n$, meaning the series is continuous on $D(0,1)$ - but I don't know how that can help with the series at $z \in \delta D(0,1)-\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that

$$(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k=a_0-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{k-1}-a_k)z^k$$

where the right side possesses a nice majorant for $|z|=1$.

---

**Update:** The trivial necessary condition for convergence implies the additional assumption $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Here, this addition is also sufficient to prove convergence. As Twink commented, the coefficient sequence $a_n\equiv 1$ gives a counter-example to the problem in its currently stated form.

Comment: Thanks! I get that it is bound by $\frac{|2a_0|}{(1-z)}$.

Comment: In order to have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$ you need $|z|<1$.

Comment: Yes, obviously one needs additionally $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ to justify the series manipulation on the partial sum level.